# typescript ERROR 2531 - "Object is possibly 'null' "

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am developing an Android app in Ionic Angular with Firebase. yesterday i had this problem
in VSC and as much as I search I can't find the solution.

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwh8C.png)

[this is the Ts from my page Register users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYrkX.png)

The problem is in the Line 41 "const id = <sub>res.user</sub>.uid; "

[models.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bbkj.png)

Help me please!.

I try to change const id = res.user.uid; to  const id = res.user?.uid;
but doesnt works

Comment: if (res.user && res.user.uid) { ...your code }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initialize your variable and make sure it's not null. if it was not enough and you are sure that variable (like `user`) won't be null, you can try

```
const id = res.user!.uid;
```

or you can suppress the error by adding this line in the right behind the part of your code with the error:

```
// @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

or you can generally disable null checking in your project in `tsconfig.json` file (which is not recommended) like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
```

Comment: Ty so much, I change the tsconfig.json and ready!